# Defining rows and columns of montage with Rmagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I have a set of images in an ImageList and I want to create a montage that is 160x600.  Here is what I am doing so far:

```
collage = image_list.montage do |mont|
  mont.background_color = "#444444"
  mont.geometry = '160x600'
end
```

I thought mont.geometry would be setting the width/height of the resulting collage but is not, I think it's actually resizing every image that is being put in the collage.

How can I ensure that the resulting collage is 160x600, and that the images that are forming it are resized accoridng to that?

Comment: I don't if it will help but I found this doc `http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#montage`

Comment: I have read through that.

Answer (score 0):

The `mont.geometry` command is in fact about each little image prior to putting them together.  You can use `image_list.size` to figure out how many images you have and then the following types of commands to put things together.

```
width = 160 / image_list.size
height = 600 / image_list.size

collage = image_list.montage do |mont|
    mont.geometry = width.to_s + 'x' + height.to_s
end
```

Things might not work well if you get into decimals.  Make sure your values divide evenly, or else rewrite the code to handle that efficiently.

Another option is to create the montage at whatever size you like first and to resize it after it's done.  They both take about the same amount of work.